# How does Google Drive handle a name conflict when you copy or move a file?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, online-storage

If I is the web interface in Google Docs to copy MyFile.txt   into a G Folder that already has MyFile.txt what happens in these scenarios?

- The file contents are the same
- The file contents are different and
  the destination is older

USE CASE DETAILS

I have a bunch of files in Folder1 that I want to copy to Folder2 but there may be some duplicates, so I want to do it in the web interface b/c I *think* it'll update all the local copies faster than if I do it on a local copy, have the server update, and then have the 3 or so PCs update their local copies.

Comment: Have you considered just testing it yourself? Create a couple of folders and some dummy files and try it.

Answer (score 1):

From a simple test, Gdrive just replaced both files.

So it would appear that Google Drive does not do any checking for duplicate filenames existing on the destination.